# Environment Configuration Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Created a Spring Boot application that will need to migrate from "Local Dev" to "Test", "QA" and "Prod" environments.

Application currently uses a "application.properties" for database connectivity and Kafka configuration.

I am wanting to deploy to "Test" and realized that the properties will not work for that enviornment. After reading the ref docs, it looks like I can simply copy the application.properties file and add a new one application-test.properties, so on, and then run the standalone jar with a -Dspring.profiles.active=test and that seems to work.

But by the time I am done, that means I h ave 4 different appliction-XXXXX.properties files in the jar which may or may not be bad. I know the ultimate configuration would be to use Spring Config server, but right now we are not there with regards to this.

Can anyone validate that using multiple properties files is viable and will work for a bit, or if I am looking at th is all wrong. I do not want to have configuration on the servers in each environment, as I am thinking these mini-services should be self-contained.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: The common properties which are not changed via environments we can keep in application.properties (application.yml). You can keep properties specifically to particular envinroments to application-test.properties or application-dev.properties ...

Comment: And supposed if you can multiple dev envinroment such as dev1, dev2 like that, you can have application-dev-base.yml contains common properties for dev and in application-dev1 you include application-dev-base.yml , like that ...

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

in a word, your configuration file should be outside your source code.

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:system.properties"})
public class EnvironmentConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Let's say it's named **"system.properties"**, which will be uploaded to server at deployment stage under your application classpath.